# Radiobutton listeners in html

Tags: html, jsp

I have two radio buttons like this,

```
 <table name="">
     <tr><input type="radio" name="passwordissues" value="forgetpassword"/>Forget Password</tr>
     <tr><input type="radio" name="passwordissues" value="resetpassword"/>Change Password</tr>
 </table>
```

I may can put this inside a form but i am not supposed to add any buttons to submit the form.

My problem is when ever i click on one of the radio button it has to perform some action or has to display something. How can achieve it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `JavaScript` handler (event function) for radio buttons that invokes the [form.submit().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit)

Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
     var radios=document.getElementsByName("passwordissues");
     var form1=document.getElementById("form1");
     for(i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
        radios[i].onclick=function() { form1.submit(); };
      }
  };
</script>

<form method="post" action="action_here" id="form1">
 <input type="radio" 
        name="passwordissues" 
        value="forgetpassword"/>Forget Password
 <input type="radio" 
        name="passwordissues" 
        value="resetpassword"/>Change Password
</form>
```

Comment: can you explain me a little bit more... and there is any way to handle this in jsp instead of using javascript?

Comment: At first, he gets all radio buttons with the name `passwordissues`. And for each radio button, he defines an event handler which simply submits the form. This isn't possible with JSP because it already executes on the server side whereas JavaScript executes on the client side.